# Using 7zip to extract .rar files but cannot find archive

Tags: python, command-line, extract, 7zip

I'm using python to automatically extract archives. I'm using subprocess as such:

```
command = "7z e " + self.dir + " -o" + dest
subprocess.call(command)
```

where self.dir is the directory of the archive (as a .rar file) and dest is the destination folder.

My issue is that it works haphazardly. For some reason it will extract some archives fine but not others. I haven't found a pattern, but I have read the command prompt and when it doesn't work it prints

```
Error:
cannot find archive
```

Annoyingly, I can extract the exact same archive using the GUI. There appears to be something wrong with my actual program.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I believe if you use a big string as a command argument then you should do subprocess.call(args,shell=True). If you know where your 7z is, then use a list of arguments instead.

Comment: @nagylzs It's not important to know where 7z is. If you do ``subprocess.call(["foo", "bar"])``, subprocess will do the neccessary lookup of "foo" for you.

Answer (score 1):

What is your current directory? Please check if your "self.dir" is a full file path, not just a relative path. Try this to check:

```
print os.path.abspath(self.dir)
print os.getcwd()
print os.path.isfile(self.dir)
```

By the way, using "dir" as an attribute name is unfortunate. `dir` is a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

I think `subprocess.call()` requires a list when you are passing arguments. Try this:

```
command = ["7z", "e", self.dir, "-o", dest]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes to your directory string. You probably have spaces that is confusing the zip program.